# Rql `or` not work while involving non-exists field

Tags: rethinkdb

version: 1.15.2

```
r.db('test')
 .table('form')
 .filter(r.row('yyy').eq('aaa').or(r.row('id').eq('aaa')))
 .limit(10)
```

Why this query cannot match a document where `id` is `aaa` but without field `yyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special handling for non-existing fields (`default: false`) so I guess it is best to rewrite the query to not call `.eq()` on a missing field. You could either check `id` first:

```
.filter(r.row('id').eq('aaa').or(r.row('yyy').eq('aaa')))
```

or maybe by setting the default behavior directly on the operation with missing fields:

```
.filter(r.row('yyy').eq('aaa').default(false).or(r.row('id').eq('aaa')))
```

BTW: an update to this answer. After reporting a documentation bug for RethinkDB it turns out, this is already mentioned in a troubleshooting guide: http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#filters-with-or-return-incorrect/unexpected-r